# Cupertino modal bottom sheet fit with inside navigation

Tags: flutter, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

Is it possible to have two modal bottom sheets with inside navigation but different height? For instance, the first bottom sheet has 3 elements and sized to its child (Column with 3 List Tiles) and the second bottom sheet is the same but has 5 elements (Column with 5 List Tiles)? Like on the image with navigation between them.

I have a feeling that when I add a Navigator it expands, takes all the available space and I can't size it to its content. A container with constraints helps, but then again both bottom sheets have the same height.

[image]

Comment: @jamesblasco, could you please take a look? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mention two bottom sheets, I would assume you want to say a single bottom sheet with inside navigation, no?

It is not possible to achieve by using a Navigator. This widget is designed to always expand to the maximum available.

You could try to use another approach, like using a Stack widget or a AnimatedCrossFade one

Comment: Yes, I meant a single bottom sheet with inside navigation. Now it's clear, thank you!